# CVS Eclipse : A resource already exists on disk

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, repository, project, cvs

This issue has been discussed earlier but i am facing it due to a separate scenario.

I am connecting to my CVS repository(hosted on UNIX) with an eclipse default plugin.

In the repository there are 2 files:
`1. abc.txt`
`2. abc.TXT`

The difference is with the case in filenames. Both are valid commits in CVS.
When i try to checkout or synchronize the repository, following error is shown:

`A resource already exists on disk 'C:\Tarun\Work\Workspaces\person\abc.txt'.`
It throws this error on abc.TXT.

I tried a few things like deleting file name from .cvs file; but it does not work and doing that large number of files will be cumbersome.

Can someone suggest a solution around this ??

Answer (score 0):

The file system on the unix server is case sensitive and so it allows both `txt` and `TXT`. The file system on your local Windows machine is case insensitive and so sees both files as the same thing.

Do you need both files? Assuming you don't, you will have to do a `cvs remove` on one of them somehow. You may be able to do it from the windows machine by calling `cvs remove` from the command line and enclosing the name in quotes, but you would be better off temporarily checking out the project on a unix machine and doing the removal. If you can log in to the unix server directly, then try that. Alternatively, one of the many Linux live boot DVDs should work fine for this too.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs. However, I need both files and hence cvs remove is not an option.

Comment: Interesting. In which case you may be out of luck as long as you are working on a Windows machine. What are the exact file names? Knowing them may help identify a suitable alternative.

Comment: There are some extremely disciplined and well cultured group by developers who commit a update_person.SQL file and then realize that it should have been update_person.sql . They commit the 2nd file and do not remove the 1st one. Multiple instances in several repositories.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds like you *don't* need both files.

Comment: But i cannot delete the incorrectly checked in file. Is there an option to enter certain file names is a .cvs file so that they are ignored while sync?

Comment: I've given you options on how to delete the files. Have you tried them? Another alternative is to ask the people who checked in the files to remove them.